# REINFORCE algorithm with discounted rewards – where does gamma^t in the update come from?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradients

I'm looking at Sutton & Barto's rendition of the REINFORCE algorithm ([from their book here, pg. 328](http://incompleteideas.net/book/the-book-2nd.html)).

[image: Sutton & Barto's REINFORCE]

I can't quite understand why there is $\gamma^t$ on the last line. They say:

> [..] in the boxed algorithms we are giving the algorithms for the general discounted [return] case. All of the ideas go through in the discounted case with appropriate adjustments [..] but involve additional complexity that distracts from the main ideas.

This doesn't quite make it clear for me.

I didn't find any other description of REINFORCE that would include this. Does anyone have an idea how the $\gamma^t$ gets there?

Comment: Later rewards should be less important than current.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right – or as a friend of mine put it, samples that have less following time steps should be less important. So the intuition is there, but I'll leave this here in case someone is able to do the math :-).

Comment: http://proceedings.mlr.press/v32/thomas14.pdf it stems from this paper